# R: How to use prdict.lm() for multivariate regression

Tags: r, lm

In case of multivariate regression (multiple responses), the `predict.lm` function does not seem to work. It predicts just the first response.

**Sample code:**

```
df = data_frame(x1 = c(1:20), 
                y1 = x1 + rnorm(20,5,sd = 5), 
                y2 = 2*x1 + rnorm(20,-5,sd = 3))


m1 = lm(cbind(y1, y2) ~ x1, data = df)
m1


## Call:
## lm(formula = cbind(y1, y2) ~ x1, data = df)

## Coefficients:
##               y1       y2     
## (Intercept)   7.5934  -5.9436
## x1            0.8704   2.0913
```

If I try to predict using this model object (for the training data or for `newdata`), it predicts only for the first response.

```
# predicts only for y1
length(predict.lm(m1))
## [1] 20 

# predicts only for y1
predict.lm(m1, newdata = data_frame(x1 = 50))
##        1 
## 51.11093
```

How can I get this function to work for multiple responses?

Comment: use `predict` so it can dispatch to `predict.mlm`

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `predict.lm` use `predict`.

```
> predict.lm(m1)
        1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9        10        11        12        13        14 
 4.210964  5.260564  6.310164  7.359764  8.409365  9.458965 10.508565 11.558166 12.607766 13.657366 14.706967 15.756567 16.806167 17.855767 
       15        16        17        18        19        20 
18.905368 19.954968 21.004568 22.054169 23.103769 24.153369  

> predict(m1)
          y1        y2
1   4.210964 -3.117932
2   5.260564 -1.024133
3   6.310164  1.069666
4   7.359764  3.163466
5   8.409365  5.257265
6   9.458965  7.351064
7  10.508565  9.444863
8  11.558166 11.538663
9  12.607766 13.632462
10 13.657366 15.726261
11 14.706967 17.820061
12 15.756567 19.913860
13 16.806167 22.007659
14 17.855767 24.101459
15 18.905368 26.195258
16 19.954968 28.289057
17 21.004568 30.382857
18 22.054169 32.476656
19 23.103769 34.570455
20 24.153369 36.664255
```